# no boot disk has been detected ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, grub2

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 4 times already and tried to fix GRUB, but it always says that no boot disk has been detected. I need help if anyone can tell me something to fix that it will by great.

Comment: you need not to install ubuntu again and again. you can reinstall grub if you have problems like that... [link to repair grub](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Comment: When you read your answer, it looks like you're saying "install it again and again" :D **Please don't** install ... would look better. ;-)

Comment: What computer & model? Installed in BIOS or UEFI mode? May be best to see details: Post link to summary report: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen if I create a USB drive WITHOUT first erasing it completely. I first made the mistake of just copying the ISO image to the drive and trying to boot it. Then I got smart  and used Disk Utility (on a Mac) to erase the drive fully, then the application "unetbootin" to create the bootable USB using a downloaded ISO image.